# How to make a div asked like position: fixed without position:fixed?

Tags: css, scroll, position

I need a div to say in the same place while the user scrolls. position: fixed; does just this - however, its messing with my responsive stuff.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "messing with my responsive stuff" is not an adequate explanation of the problem you're having.

Comment: Please add some html or fiddle that include responsive elements around the div you want be fixed so we can see whats going on. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.  It has display issues.  To be honest, I don't know what other issues   a css stye like "position" could possibly have.  I wish I could share code on this one - not to sure my boss/client would be happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Ended up using position: fixed; but added margin-right: 50%; adding the margin allowed it to continue to be responsive with the other elements.

**** EDIT ------> This worked a lot better....

> $(window).scroll(function () {
>           $("#item-1").stop().animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft": ($(window).scrollLeft())
>   + "px" }, "fast");
>       });

Answer (score 0):

How I understand you need something like display: sticky . Of course you are not able to use it now because a lot of browsers don`t support it . But You can use some libraries like : http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: Indeed! I did find the Stickyjs while I was looking for answers.  Its exactly why I need however like you said - not to many browsers support it.